# Replace NaN in DataFrame index

Tags: pandas, replace, label, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
      one | two 
a   |  2  |  5
b   |  3  |  6
NaN |  0  |  0
```

How do I replace the NaN in the index with a string, say "No label"?

I tried:

```
df = df.replace(np.NaN, "No label")
```

and

```
df.index = df.index.replace(np.NaN, "No label")
```

But got

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can process the original index as a Series first and then re-assign the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [2, 3, 0], 'two': [5, 6, 0]}, index=['a', 'b', np.nan])
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).replace(np.nan, 'No label')
print df
```

Output:

```
          one  two
a           2    5
b           3    6
No label    0    0
```

Comment: Dohhh! that's what I should've thought off. This does what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There is a `to_series` method for converting an `Index` to `Series`: `df.index = df.index.to_series().fillna('No label')` will work fine

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Index.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.fillna.html):

```
df.index = df.index.fillna('No label')
print (df)
          one  two
a           2    5
b           3    6
No label    0    0
```

Comment: Note: This does not work with MultiIndex.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs handling for the MultiIndex case too:

```py
if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
        df.index.to_frame().fillna("No label")
    )
else:
    df.index = df.index.fillna("No label")
```