# Replacing nan with None in pandas dataframe MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace nan with None in a pandas dataframe MultiIndex. It seems like
None is converted to nan in MultiIndex (but not in other index types).

Following does not work (Taken from the question [Replace NaN in DataFrame index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506689/replace-nan-in-dataframe-index))

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', True, 1], ['b', True, 2], ['c', False, 3], ['d', None, 4]], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
df.set_index(['c1','c2'], inplace=True)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.index.to_frame().fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None]))
df
          c3
c1 c2       
a  True    1
b  True    2
c  False   3
d  NaN     4
type(df.index[3][1])
<class 'float'>
```

Neither does

```
index_tuples = [tuple(row) for row in df.index.to_frame().fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None]).values]
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples)
MultiIndex([('a',  True),
            ('b',  True),
            ('c', False),
            ('d',   nan)],
           )

type(df.index[3][1])
<class 'float'>
```

It seems None is converted to NaN in MultiIndex.

PS. It works for other index types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', True, 1], ['b', True, 2], ['c', False, 3], ['d', None, 4]], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
df.set_index('c2', inplace=True)
>>> df
      c1  c3
c2          
True   a   1
True   b   2
False  c   3
NaN    d   4
>>> df.index = df.index.fillna(value=np.nan).to_series().replace([np.nan], [None])
>>> df
      c1  c3
c2          
True   a   1
True   b   2
False  c   3
NaN    d   4
>>> type(df.index[3])
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

Comment: It must be `None` or would `"None"` or something else also work?

Comment: It must be None. These dataframes go through a pipeline and transformed to other python types. Also, values are read from database, if I replace with any arbitrary string, I am worried, there will be same non-null string value in db (There can be string values like "None")

Answer (score 2):

The only way I managed to do it is by manipulating the numpy array directly. Seems like any assignment of `None` values by a `MultiIndex` in pandas results in conversion to `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', True, 1], ['b', True, 2], ['c', False, 3], ['d', None, 4]], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
df.set_index(['c1','c2'], inplace=True)

def replace_nan(x):
    new_x = []
    for v in x:
      try:
        if np.isnan(v):
          new_x.append(None)
        else:
          new_x.append(v)
      except TypeError:
        new_x.append(v)
    return tuple(new_x)


print('Before:\n', df.index)
idx = df.index.values
idx[:] = np.vectorize(replace_nan, otypes=['object'])(idx) # Replace values in np.array
print('After:\n', df.index)
```

Result:

```
Before:
 MultiIndex([('a',  True),
            ('b',  True),
            ('c', False),
            ('d',   nan)],
           names=['c1', 'c2'])
After:
 MultiIndex([('a',  True),
            ('b',  True),
            ('c', False),
            ('d',  None)],
           names=['c1', 'c2'])
```

Comment: FWIW, I think you can avoid the problem if you can create the index using `.from_product()`

Answer (score 1):

I think there could actually be a bug in Pandas here. But the following works for me in a similar situation:

`df = df.set_index(pf.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))`

The bug is that the `df.index.levels` is the same, with or without expanded indices.